# How akka actor model is used in akka http?

Tags: akka, actor, akka-http

I am studying a tutorial on akka http. But wanted to know how akka actor model is implemented in akka http. Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Akka-http is based on Akka-stream. Akka-stream is based on actor model.
2. In common, Akka-http is only an input(http request) and output(http response) channel. Business logic, distributed and cluster are implemented by Akka-cluster, Akka-stream, Akka-sharding etc